# Handling select tag via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-select

I cant figure how to simply solve this problem:

So I have simple HTML

```
<select id="lang" name="lang">
<option value="cs" selected="selected">Czech</option>
<option value="en">English</option>
<option value="it">Italian</option>
</select>
```

On the same page, I'am using ajax call to received information, If user hasn't already select language (that is not that much important). But for example: I get from ajax call value: "en". So I need to remove attribute "selected" and add it to the right option tag. (option tag where is attribute value="en"). I believe there is a simple solution, but I don't have enough skills with jQuery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set selected option of select box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680075/set-selected-option-of-select-box)

Comment: Since the question didn't get closed and you accepted the only answer, a shorter way is: `$('#lang').val(newValue)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#lang').find('option').attr('selected', false);
$('#lang').find('option[value="'+ajaxReturn+'"]').attr('selected', true);
```