# HTML - Selecting a default option in the <select> tag

Tags: php, html

I have a list of cities.

```
<select name="cities">
    <option value="nc">New city..</option>
    <option value="quetta">Quetta</option>
    <option value="karachi">Karachi</option>
    <option value="islamabad">Islamabad</option>
    <option value="khyber pukhtun khuan">Khyber Pukhtun Khuan</option>
    <option value="multan">Multan</option>
    <option value="murree">Murree</option>
    <option value="gwadar">Gwadar</option>
    <option value="gujranwala">Gujranwala</option>
    <option value="faisalabad">Faisalabad</option>
    <option value="peshawar">Peshawar</option>
</select>
```

And i have a database in which i have stored user's city. Now i am making a page in which the user will update his city and for that i want the user to see his city already selected when he opens up the page. In short, i want a option to be selected according to the value returned by the database. I am using php as the language

**I have got one solution but not implemented it yet because its not effecient! Any easy and effecient way would be appreciated.**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you provide the `PHP` code which is showing the complete list of cities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//first you have a specific city of a user

$user_city = 'city-name';

//Then you have a list of all cities available (probably from the database,
// but I use array here as an example)

$cities = array('city1','city2','city3');

<select name="cities">
   <?php
       foreach ( $cities as $city ) {
           if ( $city == $user_city ) {
              echo "<option value='".$city."' selected>$city</option>";
           } else {
              echo "<option value='".$city."'>$city</option>";
           }
       }
   ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

just check the value from database and add selected to that option by using javascript or php

```
 <option value="murree" selected >Murree</option>
```

Comment: yes, i know but then i have to run the script on every <option> tag! that's not effecient

Answer (score 1):

Get your list of cities into an array instead of hard coded HTML.

Loop over the list and output the `option` element for each.

As you do so, compare to the value retrieved from the database. Add `selected` if they match.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be to change your code structure to something more along the lines of:

```
// hardcoded cities or perhaps loaded from elsewhere
$cities = [
    "nc"        => "New city...",
    "quetta"    => "Quetta",
    "karachi"   => "Karachi"
    // ...
];

// user's city fetched from the database
$userCity = "quetta";

echo '<select name="cities">';
foreach ($cities as $key => $value)
{
    echo '<option ' . ($userCity === $key ? 'selected' : '') . ' value="' . $key . '">' . $value . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score -1):

***with JQuery***

```
$(function() {
    $("#gate").val('Gateway 2');
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CpXVB/)

[from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680075/set-selected-option-of-select-box)