# Set value of Select option in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is there any function to set value of a `<select>` tag option? I have an ajax response array and I want to put this array in a `<select>` tag.

This is my code :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://.......api/1/AbsenceType",
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function (data) {
        // It doesn't work
        var ind = document.getElementById('mySelect').selectedIndex;
        document.getElementById('mySelect').options.value="2";//
    }
})
```

And my select tag is :

```
<select id=mySelect name="mySelect" required="required" data-mini ="true" onchange="myFunction3();"/>
    <option id ="type" value=""></option>
</select>
```

Comment: what do you mean ? document.getElementById('mySelect').value="2";

Comment: do you mean you want to change the value of the option tag?

Comment: i want to add value to option tag ,, it is empty and i want to fill it with the array from ajax response .

Comment: Use $("#type").attr("value", 2); however it just only assigns the value to 1 option tag that has the id "type", for multiple options, you would require that to generate as demonstrated in the example of Shail

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I have an ajax response array and I want to put this array in a  tag.

Why don't you just add the options from the array to the select, then set the selected value, like this :

Start with an empty select :

```
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect">

</select>
```

Then use this function as a callback :

```
var callback = function (data) {

    // Get select
    var select = document.getElementById('mySelect');

    // Add options
    for (var i in data) {
        $(select).append('<option value=' + data[i] + '>' + data[i] + '</option>');
    }

    // Set selected value
    $(select).val(data[1]);
}
```

Demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/M52R9/

See :

- [Adding options to a select using Jquery/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery-javascript)
- [Set selected option of select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680075/set-selected-option-of-select-box).

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>`
</select>

$("select").val("3");
```

visit live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/y4B68/

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like that -

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/at4Qa/1/)

You can add option like this -

```
$(function(){
$("#mySelect").html('<option value="2">2</option>');
});
```

Sorry i just missed that you are doing it in `ajax callback`. i have also updated in my demo.

you can also this too-

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").innerHTML = '<option value="2">2</option>';
```

Why don't you add new option instead of adding a value in option.