# jQuery - On button click trigger select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Guys i want to ask how can i make a function in jQuery when i click a button to trigger a select of an option in a select menu.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<select id="target_menu" name="sort_by">
    <option selected="selected" id="position" value="http://cosmeo.superweb.bg/index.php/priceslider/slider/view/?dir=asc&amp;id=35&amp;max=424&amp;min=0&amp;order=position">Позиция</option>
    <option id="name" value="http://cosmeo.superweb.bg/index.php/priceslider/slider/view/?dir=asc&amp;id=35&amp;max=424&amp;min=0&amp;order=name">Име</option>
    <option id="price" value="http://cosmeo.superweb.bg/index.php/priceslider/slider/view/?dir=asc&amp;id=35&amp;max=424&amp;min=0&amp;order=price">Цена</option>
    <option id="color" value="http://cosmeo.superweb.bg/index.php/priceslider/slider/view/?dir=asc&amp;id=35&amp;max=424&amp;min=0&amp;order=color">Color</option>
    <option id="created_at" value="http://cosmeo.superweb.bg/index.php/priceslider/slider/view/?dir=asc&amp;id=35&amp;max=424&amp;min=0&amp;order=created_at">Дата</option>
</select>
```

The option which i want to be triggered as selected is `created_at`.

Here is the code of the button that i want when it is clicked to select option with id `created_at` of select menu with id `target_menu`:

```
<button onclick="triggerChange()" class="FirstFilter">
    Click me!
</button>
```

When i click on the button -> `Click Me!` i want jQuery to force/trigger a selection of option with id `created_at` at select menu with id `target_menu`.

How my function `triggerChange()` must look like ?

So guys, how can i make it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680075/set-selected-option-of-select-box

Answer (score 3):

Try this function:

```
 function triggerChange(){
        $("#target_menu").val($("#target_menu #created_at" ).val());
        $('#target_menu').trigger('change');
   }
```

Comment: Okey but does it change and select the option with id `created_at` ?

Comment: I have updated the ans. according to your requirements

Comment: What you wrote works only when you manually change the select element and no matter what a user will choose it will select option with 'created_at' id. He wanted to set 'created_at' as a selected option on button click. How your answer helps him ?

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways of doing it. One is below. A piece of advise is that do not use inline event handlers!

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
    $("#target_menu option").filter(function(opt, el) {
        return el.id === 'created_at' && $(el)
    }).prop("selected", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="target_menu" name="sort_by">
    <option selected="selected" id="position" value="http://cosmeo.superweb.bg/index.php/priceslider/slider/view/?dir=asc&amp;id=35&amp;max=424&amp;min=0&amp;order=position">Позиция</option>
    <option id="name" value="http://cosmeo.superweb.bg/index.php/priceslider/slider/view/?dir=asc&amp;id=35&amp;max=424&amp;min=0&amp;order=name">Име</option>
    <option id="price" value="http://cosmeo.superweb.bg/index.php/priceslider/slider/view/?dir=asc&amp;id=35&amp;max=424&amp;min=0&amp;order=price">Цена</option>
    <option id="color" value="http://cosmeo.superweb.bg/index.php/priceslider/slider/view/?dir=asc&amp;id=35&amp;max=424&amp;min=0&amp;order=color">Color</option>
    <option id="created_at" value="http://cosmeo.superweb.bg/index.php/priceslider/slider/view/?dir=asc&amp;id=35&amp;max=424&amp;min=0&amp;order=created_at">Дата</option>
</select>

<button class="FirstFilter">
    Click me!
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function triggerChange()
{
  $("#target_menu").val($("#created_at").val());
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<select id="target_menu" name="sort_by">
    <option selected="selected" id="position" value="http://cosmeo.superweb.bg/index.php/priceslider/slider/view/?dir=asc&amp;id=35&amp;max=424&amp;min=0&amp;order=position">Позиция</option>
    <option id="name" value="http://cosmeo.superweb.bg/index.php/priceslider/slider/view/?dir=asc&amp;id=35&amp;max=424&amp;min=0&amp;order=name">Име</option>
    <option id="price" value="http://cosmeo.superweb.bg/index.php/priceslider/slider/view/?dir=asc&amp;id=35&amp;max=424&amp;min=0&amp;order=price">Цена</option>
    <option id="color" value="http://cosmeo.superweb.bg/index.php/priceslider/slider/view/?dir=asc&amp;id=35&amp;max=424&amp;min=0&amp;order=color">Color</option>
    <option id="created_at" value="http://cosmeo.superweb.bg/index.php/priceslider/slider/view/?dir=asc&amp;id=35&amp;max=424&amp;min=0&amp;order=created_at">Дата</option>
</select>

<button onclick="triggerChange()" class="FirstFilter">
    Click me!
</button>
```

Here is an answer to your question.

```
function triggerChange()
{
  $("#target_menu").val("created_at");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as you have an id applied to each option you can target that id then use  the .prop() method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".firstFilter").click(function(){
    var id = $("#created_at").prop("selected","selected");   
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
function triggerChange(){    
$("#target_menu").eq(4).prop("selected","selected");     
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I made this fiddle for you

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9hr22oo/)

First step is to get value from element with id `created_at`:

```
var wantedValue= $('#created_at').attr('value');
```

And next, you need to set selected value for your select element:

```
$('#target_menu').val(wantedValue).trigger('change');  // need to call .trigger('change') here
// you can also call .trigger() - without 'change' keyword
```

Explanation about why you need to trigger `.change` [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672505/why-does-the-jquery-change-event-not-trigger-when-i-set-the-value-of-a-select-us)

> For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired
>   immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for
>   the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses
>   focus.

**Update** ( thanks LShetty )

```
$('.FirstFilter').click(function(){
       $("#position").removeAttr("selected");
       $("#created_at").attr('selected','selected');
    });
```

Comment: Why trigger `change` when there is no capture?

Comment: Before giving -1  search :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672505/why-does-the-jquery-change-event-not-trigger-when-i-set-the-value-of-a-select-us

Comment: Well, I didn't give -1 by the way! You're consfusing `change` to setting a selected value. What OP wants is to set the selected value by clicking on a button! So, `change` is irrelevant here and `change` is not even bound to the `select`

Comment: Oh! Right! :) .. I understand what you're trying to say. My mind exploded when I read his question :))