# Select2 - display selected item after refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use select2 to (https://select2.github.io) to bulding drop down list. I have problem with display selected item after refresh the page (my select is stored in DB). Where excalcly have I add select or selected="selected" ?
I can't add this in  because every user of my website selects own item in his settings.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".js-example-basic-single").select2({
});
$("select").select2({
});
});          
</script>
<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="field">
  <option value="city1">city1</option>
   <option value="city2">city2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set selected option of select box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680075/set-selected-option-of-select-box)

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var storedValue = 'city2';
  var $select = $(".js-example-basic-single").select2({});
  $select.select2('val', 'storedValue');
});          
</script>
<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="field">
  <option value="city1">city1</option>
   <option value="city2">city2</option>
</select>
```

How you get the stored value from your server is up to you / stack. If you don't have a backend you can use `localStorage` to store what the user selected.