# Setting Select option

Tags: jquery

I have some select dropdowns

```
            <div class="selector">
                <div class="nomination selectors-part">Year</div>
                <div class="selection mini">
                    <select name="seltoYear">
                        <option selected disabled>Till</option>
                        <option value="2015">2015</option>
                        <option>2014</option>
                        <option>2013</option>
                        <option>2012</option>
                        <option>2011</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="selection mini">
                    <select name="selfromYear">
                        <option selected disabled>From</option>
                        <option>1956</option>
                        <option>1986</option>
                        <option>1993</option>
                        <option>1994</option>
                        <option>1995</option>
                        <option>1996</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
```

I trying to set selected value back after POSt, but nothing hapins

```
$(function() {

$('div.list input[type=checkbox]').on('change',onValueChange);     
$('div.selector select').on('change', onValueChange);

function onValueChange() {

    var Checked = {};
    var Selected = {};
// Hold all checkboxes
    $('div.list input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
        var $el = $(this);
        var name = $el.attr('name');
        if (typeof (Checked[name]) === 'undefined') {
            Checked[name] = [];
        }
        Checked[name].push($el.val());
    });
// Hold all dropdowns
    $('div.list select').each(function () {

        var $el = $(this);
        var name = $el.attr('name');

        if (typeof (Selected[name]) === 'undefined') {
            Selected[name] = [];
        }
        Selected[name].push($el.val());
    });

// Put all together to POST 
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Search.asp',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $.param(Checked) + "&" + $.param(Selected),
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#ExSearchForm").html(data)
                .find('div.list input[type=checkbox],div.selector select').each(function () {
                    var $el = $(this);
                    var name = $el.attr('name');
                    var value = $el.attr('value');

                    if (Checked[name] && Checked[name].indexOf(value) !== -1) {
                        $el.prop('checked', true);
                    }
                    if (Selected[name] && Selected[name].indexOf(value) !== -1) {
                        $el.prop('selected', true);
                    }
                });
        }
    });
};
});
```

Checkboxes are selecting as well but dropdowns do not want to be selected.

Comment: `<select>` has no attribute `value`, so `$el.attr('value')` is `undefined` for it. You can use `$el.val()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the select elements, you have to use `val()` like

```
if (Selected[name] && Selected[name].indexOf(value) !== -1) {
   $el.val(value);
}
```

Note, the way you calculate `value` will not work as your `select` element does not have an **attribute** of `value`

See [Set selected option of select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680075/set-selected-option-of-select-box)

**Update**

Change

```
 $('div.list select').each(function () {

    var $el = $(this);
    var name = $el.attr('name');

    if (typeof (Selected[name]) === 'undefined') {
        Selected[name] = [];
    }
    Selected[name].push($el.val());
});
```

to

```
   $('div.list select').each(function () {

        var $el = $(this);
        var name = $el.attr('name');

        Selected[name] = $el.val();
    });
```

and

```
if (Selected[name] && Selected[name].indexOf(value) !== -1) {
     $el.prop('selected', true);
 }
```

to

```
if (Selected[name]) {
    $el.val(Selected[name]);
}
```

Comment: Thank for answer but nothing happins

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin, can you replicate it in a fiddle or show me how the `data` looks like in the success callback?

Comment: In callback i get full HTML with formed code like in my question

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin, ok and from teh example above, which `option` value do you want to be selected?

Comment: i need to select value which is in Selected object where Select tag name=Name and option text=text. Or this value which was selected before sending POST. Just want to restore selected value? as after post all checkboxes and dropdowns is reseting

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin, try ` $el.val(Selected[name][0]);`

Comment: Sorry, try `$el.val(Selected[name][Selected[name].length - 1]);`

Comment: Nope (( Maybe it happins because exist previous selected prop ?

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin, try the last one above

Comment: Sorry but no selecting, in request i get strange names with added array brackets `[]`  ? `seltoYear[0]=&selfromYear[]=1956`

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin, can you replicate it in a fidle?

Comment: Sorry i do not know how to do that i just start to learn jquery

Comment: Blah, i dont understand anything now ((( then i do `alert($el.val(Selected[name]));` it work as well if do`$el.val(Selected[name]);` it not works

Comment: Oh i found mistake in Posting page, averything works now, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if (Selected[name] && Selected[name].indexOf(value) !== -1) {
    $el.attr('selected', 'selected');
}
```