# Jquery comboboxes, selection in code

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I have two jquery comboboxes populated with various options:

```
<select id="project">
    <option value="1">This is project 1</option>
    <option value="2">This is project 2</option>
</select>
<select id="tasks">
     <option value="1">This is task 1</option>
     <option value="2">This is task 2</option>
</select>
```

I haven't shown all the html that the comobobox script adds which includes text boxes.  The problem is when I make a selection from the first combo I want to script a selection in the 2nd comobobox, but for some reason I can't get the selection to show.

I would create a jsfiddle to demostrate the problem but I don't know how to link resources.

I've tried setting the selectedIndex member or calling the val() method, no luck.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4680075) related?

Comment: what value you need to select in the second combobox ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am using the jquery combobox, calling the "val" method with a value in any of the options does not cause the input text box to update.

Comment: I want the selections to show the text associated with the values set.

Comment: you need the related text to be show in the second compobox right ? see the answers

Comment: [check this](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) please

Comment: [See This](http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/01/jquery-playing-with-select-dropdownlistcombobox/) it could help you

Comment: Thats great for a normal drop down list, but not for a combobox.

Comment: [see this](https://github.com/adamcoulombe/jquery.customSelect/issues/22)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98854/discussion-between-alaa-m-jaddou-and-splatten).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution as discussed with "Alla M. Jaddou" was to add an id to the input box created by the $.widget( "custom.combobox", {}); callback.

In the createAutocomplete method I get the id assigned to the select element:

```
    id = this.element[0].id;
```

I then add an id attribute to the input box with the prefix "inp".

When a selection is changed in the combo I then get the input element and set the text.

Answer (score 1):

i think this is what you need

let's say you need to change task value to be like project value

```
$('#project').change(function() {
    $('#tasks').val('here_is_the_related_second_value');
});
```

**UPDATE 1**

could you try this:

```
$("#project").combobox({ 
    select: function (event, ui) { 
        $('#tasks').val('here_is_the_related_second_value');
    } 
});
```

[See This](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-set-a-dropdown-box-value-in-jquery/)

Comment: Sorry no that doesn't work, and using the combobox I do not get the change event.

Comment: @SPlatten can you explaine what exactly the functionality will be ? i mean you need to type into a combobox and when typing change the value is that what you need ?

Comment: What i want to do is make a selection from the first combo, then according to the selection lookup the task from an internal object and set the task, updating the second combo to display the task.

Comment: @SPlatten could you please give me how the object look like so i can make a solution please

Comment: Yes, thats what I'm doing and it works for the first combo, however my problem is that I have a second combo and I want to set the value in the second combo when the first is changed.

Comment: @SPlatten Please could you see the update of my answer

Comment: If I knew my way around jsFiddle better I would post a link with a demo to show off the problem, but I'm not sure how to link scripts on jsFiddle.  Sorry, I just read your answer again, I will try and post when I have the result.

Comment: Unforunately whilst this might set the selected element, the <select> list is hidden, the input box that is used for the text entry is still empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98852/discussion-between-alaa-m-jaddou-and-splatten).

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#project').change(function(e){
    var itemToSelect = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    $('#tasks').val(itemToSelect);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<select id="project">
    <option value="1">This is project 1</option>
    <option value="2">This is project 2</option>
</select>
<select id="tasks">
    <option value="1">This is task 1</option>
    <option value="2">This is task 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The combobox box isn't a simple selection it adds a text entry box and autocomplete selection, setting the value using the "val" method does not update the text box.  The "select" elements are hidden from view.

Comment: @SPlatten I understand but to give you more I need more info. There a lot of different autocomplete selection so which one do you use?

Comment: The scripts I am using:  jquery-2.1.4.min.js, jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: @SPlatten and for the selection autocomplete?

Comment: jdq widgets "jqxcombobox.js", jQWidgets v3.6.0