# Change option value of select box on calling function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am using select box in which I have two options. When I click on one option named "Reposition cover" it calls the JavaScript function. After function calling, it displays the "Reposition cover" in select box (default behavior of select box), but I want to display the default value ('Change' in my case) in select box once the function is called.
And when the user will again click on "Reposition cover" option, the function will again call and select box will return it's default value and so on.
Following is my code that I wrote to achieve this:

Html

```
<select id="cars">
  <option value="change" selected="selected">Change</option>
  <option value="rep">Reposition cover</option>
    <div>Reposition cover</div>

</select>
```

Javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){
     e1 = document.getElementById('cars');
    if(e1)
    {
        e1.addEventListener('change', function() {
        if(this.value == 'rep'){
         repositionCover();
          /*Execute your script */
        }
        else
        {
    
            }
    });
        }
     
     
    });
     </script>
```

Comment: This has been asked countless times before, please google before asking

Comment: @vsync
Mr. I googled it alot of times but not find any solution that's why i posted the question. What's wrong in it ?

Comment: The accepted answer is nothing different the countless other answers in past questions found on the first few google results, which contradicts your previous comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set selected option of select box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680075/set-selected-option-of-select-box)

Comment: @vsync
No ways Mr. Compare both issues then decide about duplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reset the value of the select

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#cars').on('change', function() {
    if(this.value == 'rep'){
      this.value = 'change';
      //repositionCover();
    } else {
      
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cars">
  <option value="change" selected="selected">Change</option>
  <option value="rep">Reposition cover</option>
  <div>Reposition cover</div>

</select>
```

Comment: Thanx, i am new on javascript that's why asked such a basic question.
Anyways, thanx