# Get Selected Option by Value

Tags: jquery, select

Firstly, apologize you find this really duplicates with other questions but since I'm already try most of the solutions given, but still stuck in the middle, then this is my last choice for getting the solutions.
I've try the examples like this:

```
var user_dept = val[0].user_dept;
$('#user_dept option:selected').attr('value', user_dept);
```

and

```
var user_dept = val[0].user_dept;
$('#user_dept option[value="'+user_dept+'"]').attr('selected', true);
```

and as well this:

```
$('#user_dept').append($('<option>',{
        value: val[0].user_dept,
      }));
```

But couldn't get the issues solved. FYI, I declare all these codes inside if statement on jQuery. Wish to get the answers for jquery if possible since I'm using jquery for my work.

Edited:

As I mention on these comments below, I get the select option generated by this function,

```
function UserDept()
{
  $.getJSON('user_management_lib.php?mode=getDepartmentList', function(data){
    var list = [];
    $.each(data, function(index, value){
      list += '<option value="'+value['department_id']+'">'+value['department']+'</option>'
    });
    $('#user_dept').html(list);
  });
}
```

But as for selected option, I need to get this done by value which are equal to `user_dept` column from distinct table which is totally unrelated to function above. Since I use jQuery and array, I will declare this in `$('#user_dept').val(val[0].user_dept);`. I will clarify if necessary. Sorry for any inconveniences.

Edited on 30/12/2016:
Code below is the callback function using ajax where this question also included. So, it's quite incomplete since I'm playing around to fix this.

```
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  url: 'ldap_lib.php',
  data:'mode=findLDAPServerInfo&ldapid=<?php echo $target_lid; ?>',
  type:'POST',
  dataType:'json',
  success: function(val){
    UserDept();
    UserRole();
    GlobalDept();
    $('#mode').val('editLDAPServer');
    $('#l_name').val(val[0].l_name);
    $('#l_desc').val(val[0].l_desc);
    $('#l_ip1').val(val[0].l_ip1);
    $('#l_port1').val(val[0].l_port1);
    $('#l_ip2').val(val[0].l_ip2);
    $('#l_port2').val(val[0].l_port2);
    $('#l_domainname').val(val[0].l_domain);
    $('#l_loginname').val(val[0].l_loginname);
    $('#l_loginpwd').val(val[0].l_loginpwd);
    $('#l_mobile').val(val[0].l_mobile);
    $('#l_basedn').val(val[0].l_basedn);
    $('#l_filter').val(val[0].l_filter);
    $('#l_type').val(val[0].l_type);
    $('#l_loginmode').val(val[0].l_loginmode);
    $('#l_scope').val(val[0].l_scope);
    $('#sync_frequency').val(val[0].sync_frequency);
    $('#sync_time').val(val[0].sync_hour);

    if(val[0].sync_ul == 't'){
      $('#l_sync_ul').prop('checked', true);
      $('#tip_ul_dept').attr('style','display:block');
      var user_dept = val[0].user_dept;
      var user_role = val[0].user_role;
      //$('#user_dept option[value="'+user_dept+'"]').attr('selected', true);
      //$('#user_role option[value="'+user_role+'"]').attr('selected', true);
      //$('#user_dept option:selected').attr('value', user_dept);
      console.log($("#user_dept option"));
    } else{
      $('#l_sync_ul').prop('checked', false);
      $('#tip_ul_dept').attr('style','display:none');
    }
    if(val[0].sync_gab == 't'){
      $('#l_sync_gab').prop('checked', true);
      $('#tip_gab_dept').attr('style','display:block');
      // $('#gab_dept').val(val[0].gab_dept);
    } else{
      $('#l_sync_gab').prop('checked', false);
      $('#tip_gab_dept').attr('style','display:none');
    }
    //$('#gab_dept').val(val[0].gab_dept);
    $('#user_dept').val(val[0].user_dept);
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('Failed To Retrieve Server');
  }
});
```

Comment: are you using any plugin for select ?

Comment: I used bootstrap-template for my project but no idea if any plugin used for this. sorry for unsatisfied answer.

Comment: can you copy your html code of select here?

Comment: <select name="user_dept" id="user_dept"></select>

Comment: if your select code is totally like that this solves the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680075/set-selected-option-of-select-box or the cause of not working is somewhere else in your html. Maybe there is also given id #user_dept in your code

Comment: @WafieAli what exactly is it you're trying to do? The code samples you've provided all do different things, and none of them do what you've described in the post title.

Comment: since I use jquery, most of process is doing in jquery inside <script> tag, thus I need to make the attribute 'value' of <option> meets the column value from database table.

Comment: jQuery wraps all the selection mechanics for you. Just use `val()` on the `select` to get or set the current selection option value.

Comment: It's still not clear to me. Are you trying to populate the select box with option elements corresponding to the rows in your database?

Comment: If I understand your questions, I need to make one of the options gets selected based on column value from database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply trying to get the value of the select element, that is, the value of the currently selected option element belonging to the select element, you can use jQuery's `.val()` function: `$('#user_dept').val()`.

If you are trying to get the option element which has a given value, as your post title indicates, use `$('#user_dept option(value="' + val + '")')`.

The above assumes that `val` is a string/string-like value - you've used `val[0]` in your code sample which indicates `val` is an array. Use `val[0]` if that's the case.

**Edit**
You are trying to set the value of the select element before the select options have been created (they're generated asynchronously from a JSON request).

Make sure that the options have been generated before doing this - I've [updated your JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afkjm2rg/1/) with an example of how you might do this.

Comment: is inside .val() need to put value, like .val('sc123455')?

Comment: I've try the answers above & make it like this `$('#user_dept').val(val[0].user_dept);` but still doesnt work. Here is my html code related to this
`<select name="user_dept" id="user_dept"><option value="CC162981256010950">local1</option><option value="CC162981257010951">local2</option><option value="CC162981257010952">local3</option><option value="CC162981257010953">local4</option><option value="CC163271427011230">local5</option></select>`

Comment: no errors but no option selected. supposedly val is equal to `val[0].user_dept`. `user_dept` is a column in database table.

but the whole select option is generated by this syntax:
`function GlobalDept()
{
  $.getJSON('user_management_lib.php?mode=getDepartmentList', function(data){
    var list = [];
    $.each(data, function(index, value){
      list += '<option value="'+value['department_id']+'">'+value['department']+'</option>'
    });
    $('#gab_dept').html(list);
  });
}`

Do I have to make any conditions to match the value from database to the value from this functions?

Comment: We need the actual value of that variable. Do `console.log(val)` and let us know the result.

Comment: here's the result from `console.log(val[0].user_dept);` : CC162981257010951

Comment: The `option` elements have to be present in the DOM when you use the `.val(val[0].user_dept)` statement. If there are no options present, there'll be nothing for that function to select. A possibility is that since you're loading the options asynchronously (using `getJSON`), the options are being loaded after you try to select the option. Move the `.val(...` to the  end of the `getJSON` callback function and see if that works.

Comment: I try this `$('#user_dept').val(val[0].user_dept);` as you said to end off callbacks but still doesn't work. I expected all select options to be appeared but just one to be selected based on `.val(val[0].user_dept);`

Comment: We need to see what the state of the DOM is when you use that `.val` function. Do `console.log($("#user_dept option"))`

Comment: Here is the result : `Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → ldap_edit.php, selector: "#user_dept option" }  ldap_edit.php:427:7`

Comment: Ok that means there are no option elements present when you try to make the selection (`length: 0`). Check the final line of code in your comment above, it uses the ID `gab_dept`, did you intend this to be `user_dept`?

Comment: I'm really sorry buddy for wrong function posted. here is the right one, `function UserDept()
{
  $.getJSON('user_management_lib.php?mode=getDepartmentList', function(data){
    var list = [];
    $.each(data, function(index, value){
      list += '<option value="'+value['department_id']+'">'+value['department']+'</option>'
    });
    $('#user_dept').html(list);
  });
}`

gab_dept is for another select element, but for this case, I want to focus for user_dept first.

Comment: Ok. Can you confirm you've moved `.val(val[0].user_dept)` to the end of the callback function, after `$('#user_dept').html(list);`? Make sure that `val[0].user_dept` is still the value you expect when used in this new location.

Comment: sorry I will continue this tomorrow on Malaysia Time since I gotta go. Really appreciated your great support. I will try to make this solve ASAP.

Comment: I've done you said but still didn't manage to work. Is there anything I'm still missing?

Comment: Can you put your code into a JSFiddle? I'll take a look at it there if you like.

Comment: As suspected you are trying to set the value of the select box before the option elements are loaded. `UserDept()` returns immediately, but the option elements are generated until after the JSON request it fires is completed. See the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afkjm2rg/1/).

Comment: still the same, not working. is it because it looks for option value text, not value attribute instead?
Console are showing this error:
`ReferenceError: val is not defined[Learn More]
UserDept/<
n.Callbacks/i
n.Callbacks/j.fireWith
z
.send/c/<
`

Comment: As above, "Make sure that `val[0].user_dept` is still the value you expect when used in this new location. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afkjm2rg/2/)

Comment: it's worked as I amend this in this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afkjm2rg/3/). I will try this example to another select element. feel free to edit your main answer to this solutions, so I can credit you. this is the way I can appreciate all your helps to way out from this.