# How to set jquery value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How will i set selected value=Booking.

```js
$('#status').val("Booking");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="status" class="form-control">
   <option value="" id="status">New</option>
    <option value="">Follow</option>
    <option value="">DND</option>
   <option value="">Dead</option>
</select>
```

Comment: All your `value=""` attributes are empty. That's not a good thing. Either fill them with (uique) values or omit them in the first place

Comment: `Booking` seems not to be a value which any of the options has.

Comment: There should be an option with value 'Booking'

Comment: But i want there booking value from jquery and it should be selected

Comment: actually, your code is working, it is setting `booking` to the `value` property of the elem `option#status`. I saw no errors, if you inspect the element you'll see the value there

Comment: <select name="status" class="form-control">
                        <option value="1">New</option>
                        <option value="2">Follow</option>
                        <option value="3">DND</option>
                        <option value="4">Dead</option>
                    </select>

Comment: @user10954362 but where is `Booking` that you're looking to get?

Comment: [Set selected option of select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680075/set-selected-option-of-select-box/4680101) Try this soluction.

Comment: @Nofi that's exactely what he has done already

Comment: @user10954362 Do you mean that you want to add a new option the the select, when it is not present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to follow the below example. there is no booking option in your select add it like below code

```
$('#mySelect')
         .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",key)
                    .text("Booking"));
```

Comment: but it is not selected

Comment: Execute you code after adding the option ```$('#status').val("Booking");```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select id="status" class="form-control">
   <option value="">New</option>
    <option value="">Follow</option>
    <option value="">DND</option>
   <option value="">Dead</option>
  <option value="Booking">Booking</option>
</select>
```

and the script should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#status').val("Booking");
});
```

Also I have changed the name attribut to id since you are referring it using the '#' :)

Answer (score 0):

There should be any value of option like below so when you want to select booking option. so according to me it should be like that  please check Is that matching with your requirement.`<option value="new">New</option>`