# Why select() method is not working in Combobox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to do in Combobox exact things that I do with in textbox. When the page loads Combobox first value with like `Focus().select()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sel_bookID').focus().select();
});
```

```html
<input type=text id="sel_bookID" value="ddddddddd" name='userid1'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Like this when page load

[image]

Comment: but a dropdown doesn't have a text input - so what do you want to be selected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set selected option of select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680075/set-selected-option-of-select-box)

Comment: Are you talking about [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)?

Answer (score 0):

You can set an `option` as the default using the `selected` attribute:

```html
<select>
  <option>Opt 1</option>
  <option selected="true">Opt 2</option>
  <option>Opt 3</option>
</select>
```

However, if you really want to use jQuery to do this you can use `.prop` method:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#opt2').prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Opt 1</option>
  <option id="opt2">Opt 2</option>
  <option>Opt 3</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your trying to do like this?

```
<select id="sel_bookID">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($("#sel_bookID option:selected").text());
});
```

or maybe you only need autofocus please check this link on [**select autofocus**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_autofocus.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sel_bookID').focus().select();
    });



        <select id="sel_bookID" name='userid1'>
            <option value="ddddddddd">ddddddddd</option>
        </select>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```